# Is there a way to find out what votes were reverted from a remove user?

Tags: support, reputation, users

For example a user was removed and I gained 2 reputation from them in total before. That means that I lost 2 reputation. Is there a way to find out about what sorts of voting activity was done in my account from that user?

Comment: [sometimes it's possible...](https://plus.google.com/+MarkTrapp/posts/jQzpvHwYQVE "'Because I was a prolific user, I had thousands of votes—both up and down—and I commented extensively. Because users could see which posts were downvoted, they easily and correctly determined my account was deleted and all the downvotes on their profiles were because of me...'")

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't find out who voted for what - the problem highlighted by gnat in his comment has been address by basically not removing the votes of prolific voters.

That would make voting non-secret.

It's a big part of why you can't self delete if you've voted at all and moderators can't delete if you've voted a lot. The team have to evaluate the impact of deleting your account and take the appropriate action.